# Do Cat5e Or Cat6?

Tags: ethernet, network-monitoring, cat6, cat5e, power-over-ethernet

I recently purchased a pretty-sweet security system. And, Wow! I paid lots of money for it! However, the cables that were provided (Cat5e Ethernet) are of poor quality --too short and not weather rated! Grrr! 
The cameras will be connected to an NVR (Network Video Recorder) and they are POE (Power Over Ethernet) type cameras.
My Question is: Do I upgrade to Cat6 Ethernet Cables or stick with Cat5e? Does it make a difference with a POE/NVR Camera System? 
Be mindful, I must run 3 Ethernet cables at a distance of at least 200 feet. I have read Cat6 cables don't preform at it's max with longer distances. Is this a fact? 
Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have already asked this question here http://superuser.com/questions/1052997/do-i-do-cat5e-or-cat6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I voted to close because, really, any answer is an opinion.

Cat6 cables will perform better over long distances then cat5E cables, however I do not expect that this will make a difference - both CAT5 and CAT6 are rated to work at up to 328 feet [ ie to push maximum throughput at that distance], and I'd be surprised if your system required the additional noise cancelling [ but future proofing etc...    ]

Also, if the cabling is "in wall" or pretty fixed, go for solid cable, it has lower attentuation then stranded (and is the correct tool for the job)

Cat6 cable should always perform as well as, or better then CAT5E cable, so your distance concerns are a non-starter.